# PowerBI / DAX calculation between two dates for last 5 days

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerapps

I am trying to show a bar graph that shows the total waiting for review for each day of the last 5 days. something like this, day is 4th, 5th, 6th jan.
[image]

The data i have is a start date and end date, if the day is between those two days the status is waiting for review. What i would like is on bar graph with days on x axis and total waiting for review on y axis. So we can look at the graph and say there was 10 on this day etc.

The graph above is just the end date using this formula:

```
OutputCerts = CALCULATE(COUNT(JobID[HSNo]),USERELATIONSHIP(JobID[WLPDispatchDate],Calender[Date]))
```

but i am unsre of how to get to what i want. I think im going in the wrong direction with the above.

Comment: this can be easily solved using a snapshot table, as explained in this article https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/analyzing-events-with-a-duration-in-dax/

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this but not managed to get it to work. It produces the same number on each day

Comment: Can you post some sample data? You can easily insert a table in your post using https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this formula:

_openRecords =
VAR date_to_examine =
MAX(Calender[Date])
VAR number_orders =
CALCULATE(
DISTINCTCOUNT(JobID[HSNo]),
KEEPFILTERS(date_to_examine > JobID[StartDate] &&  JobID[StartDate]<>BLANK()),
KEEPFILTERS(date_to_examine < WorkCardReview[ApproveDate] || WorkCardReview[ApproveDate]=BLANK())

```
)
```

RETURN
IF (ISBLANK(number_orders), 0, number_orders)

works nicely with slice filter for date

Comment: This might be an useful answer but it is formatted poorly.